# Apache Drill with mongodb. Query for documents with particular keys and values within a map

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache-drill

I use apache drill with mongodb. My documents in mongodb look like this:

```
{
  "labels": [{
              "key": "product",
              "value": "shampoo"
              },
              {
               "key": "id",
               "value": "1"
               },
              {
               "key": "number",
               "value": "0"
               }]
 },
 "labels": [{
              "key": "product",
              "value": "shampoo"
              },
              {
               "key": "id",
               "value": "2"
               },
              {
               "key": "number",
               "value": "1"
               }]
 }
```

And I want to query for documents which have e. g. a label {"key": "id", "value": "1"}

I tried it with this query:

```
select * from myCollection where `labels.key` = 'id' and `labels.value` = '1';
```

It should return only the first document, but it returns both, because the second document has a label with key = number and value = 1 (it is so because of the value).

Is there a possibility to obtain only the first document? How the query should look like?

Drill converts the collection to such table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
                                labels
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
[{"key": "product", "value": "shampoo"}, {"key": "id", "value": "1"},...]
[{"key": "product", "value": "shampoo"}, {"key": "id", "value": "2"}, ...]
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This might be a logical issue. Essentially you are asking Drill to give you any result which holds both 'id' in 'key' and '1' in 'value. Besides the fact that numbers should be stored as numbers you will get both rows since key: id and value: 1 is correct for the second entry in the first label; also  key: id is correct for the second entry in the second label AND value is 1 for the third entry in the second label AND value is 2 for the second entry... a lot of true states. You want to combine them, Drill sees them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Apache Drill.

In MongoDB you would express this criterion using the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator, for example:

```
db.collection.find(
   { labels: { $elemMatch: { key: "id", value: "1" } } }
)
```

However, Apache Drill's Mongo storage plugin does not support the `$elemMatch` operator.

The [original documentation for Apache Drill's Mongo storage plugin](https://drill.apache.org/blog/2014/11/19/sql-on-mongodb/) stated:

> As of now, predicate pushdown is implemented for the following filters: >, >=, <, <=, ==, !=, isNull and isNotNull.

Looking at the [latest version of the code](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/storage-mongo/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/mongo/MongoFilterBuilder.java) this remains the case so ... no support for `$elemMatch` and there is no relational operator which can perform this match for you.